# Entity Framework, Transactions

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

Our system manages N data dases which all of them share the same tables (standard tables), but in addition each data base has its own specific tables too.

The modules which access the standard tables are programmed in the core. To access specefic tables we load assemblies by reflection in which there are a specific assembly for every data base.

How can we solve an operation which works with standard tables (core programming) and specific ones (due to reflection) in which the whole operation is in a transaction?.

We can not use 2 EF context, due to we are not able to use distributed transaction

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you do with the assemblies that are loaded via reflection? Do you read what tables you need to work with? You should explain that in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same connection string for both DbContexts, you do not need a distributed transaction with EF6, as you can pass a SqlTransaction that you own to each DbContext - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx under the "Passing an existing transaction to the context" heading

Comment: Thx, I begun working according to you advise and i made some progress. 

ctx1 c1 = new ctx1();


ctx2 c2 = new ctx2(c1.Database.Connection, false);

var lCtasQry = (from p in c2.plan_de_cuentas
                            select p)


but I receive the exception  "throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();"  



I read that i had to put that information in the method 


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Ask a new question, please